# DataTables: Adding custom attribute for rows when data is loaded via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, custom-attributes

I wonder if anyone else has faced this problem prior. I am loading data into a `DataTable` via ajax. I am trying to add custom attribute `rel` to each rows.

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652478/jquery-datatables-plugin-how-to-specify-row-attributes-when-adding-rows-to-tabl) but it is loading data directly. I could not figure out how to add the custom attribute.

My initialisation code is:

```
$('#DataTable').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "bStateSave": true,
    "bProcessing": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo site_url().$page_name.'/get_data/'?>",
    "aoColumns": [
                 { "mData": "Column1", sClass: "center "},
                 { "mData": "Column2", sClass: "center "},
                 { "mData": "Column3", sClass: "center "},
                 { "mData": "Column4", sClass: "center "},
                 { "mData": "Column5", sClass: "center "}
                 ]
});
```

The data rows gets populated. Now the problem is the one or more data may have similar parent so i want to add a custom attribute to find the rows with same parent and take them to edit on double click of any rows.

How can i add the custom attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [fnCreatedRow callback](http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnCreatedRow) i was able to add custom attribute.

Example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            // Bold the grade for all 'A' grade browsers
            if ( aData[4] == "A" )
            {
                $('td:eq(4)', nRow).html( '<b>A</b>' );
            }
        }
    });
});
```